# When using XML::Twig in Perl, the method "parent" returns also the children (not wanted)

Tags: perl, parent, perl-module, xml-twig, ancestor

I need to display the "parent" from the first Element of input.xml

Also I must display the id from the parent

Here is my script Perl:  C:\lng> C:\lng\uniq.pl

The output is displaying unfortunately the children nodes:

```
 <source id="berlin"> 
   <target id="karlsruhe" method="delete"/> 
   <target id="Stuttgart4" method="delete"/>
</source>
```

The expected output is:

```
<source id="berlin">
```

Please help.

Here is uniq.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
my $t= XML::Twig->new;
my $v= XML::Twig::Elt->new;

$t-> parsefile ('input.xml');
$v= $t->first_elt('[@method]');

$w= $v->parent;
$w->print;
```

The input file: input.xml

```
<Germany>
 <airport id1="1">
  <plane id="3">
   <source id="berlin">
     <target id="karlsruhe" method="delete"/>
     <target id="Stuttgart4" method="delete"/>
   </source>
  </plane>
 </airport>
</Germany>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `print` on an element, it prints the element, the entire element, from start tag to end tag, including all children and their descendants.

What you want it just the start tag, using the `start_tag` method:

```
print $w->start_tag;
```

Comment: superb, exactly what I needed. Thanks so much for the fast reply. But if I had to find this method described over the internet, is there an URL where I can find those useful methods (start_tag) ?

Comment: http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/ has all the docs, but to be honest `start_tag` is not one that's often used, if you want the tag name and the id, usually you would use `tag` and `id`, by using `start_tag` you risk getting other attributes of the element. You can also (on *nix) do `man XML::Twig` or `perldoc XML::Twig`

Comment: thank you for those details.  By using start_tag, I get exactly what I needed